# Grouping every three items together in list - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list consisting of a repeating patterns i.e.

```
list=['a','1','first','b','2','second','c','3','third','4','d','fourth']`
```

I am not sure how long this list will be, it could be fairly long, but I want to create list of the repeating patters i.e. along with populated names

```
list_1=['a','1','first']
list_2=['b','2','second']
list_3=['c','3','third']
..... etc
```

What is the best, basic code (not requiring import of modules) that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Suggest you don't use `list` as a variable name, as this hides python's `list` type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the chunks using `zip()`:

```
>>> lst = ['a','1','first','b','2','second','c','3','third','4','d','fourth']
>>> list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*3))
[('a', '1', 'first'), ('b', '2', 'second'), ('c', '3', 'third'), ('4', 'd', 'fourth')]
```

Using `zip()` avoids creating intermediate lists, which could be important if you have long lists.

`zip(*[iter(lst)]*3)` could be rewritten:

```
i = iter(lst)   # Create iterable from list
zip(i, i, i)    # zip the iterable 3 times, giving chunks of the original list in 3
```

But the former, while a little more cryptic, is more general.

If you need names for this lists then I would suggest using a dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'list_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(zip(*[iter(lst)]*3), 1)}
>>> d
{'list_1': ('a', '1', 'first'),
 'list_2': ('b', '2', 'second'),
 'list_3': ('c', '3', 'third'),
 'list_4': ('4', 'd', 'fourth')}
>>> d['list_2']
('b', '2', 'second')
```

Comment: `zip(*[iter(l)]*3)` this is a nice incantation, but this answer would be greatly improved if you were to explain what's happening here as it's clear as regex to a novice.

Comment: This is also much better than the original naive zip solution in that it can be generalized to chunks of any desired size.

Comment: There is a subtle point here. To understand this more precisely, you need to know that `[iter(lst)] * 3` returns a list of three references to THE SAME OBJECT. We then do a bit of a sleight of hand: we use the `*` operator to pass these objects to the `zip` function. The `zip` function forces evaluation of this single iterator, in groups of three, which happens one at a time from left to right, until the iterator runs out of items to iterate.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the call to `list` in `list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*3))` is gratuitous, since `zip` already returns a list.

Comment: `zip()` does not return a list in Py3

Comment: Ah, good point. So omitting the `list` in py3 makes this nicely lazy? Better and better!

Comment: Ah sorry guys, this is for Python 2.7. Will this still work? Also, is this the exact code I use? What do the >>> symbols mean?

Comment: @user88720 Yes, this will work fine in either 2 or 3. The `>>>` symbols indicate that we're looking at a python shell session

Comment: To be more precise: if you define a function `chunkify(lst, n)` to return `zip(*[iter(l)]*3)`, you can then use `chunkify` to break a list `lst` into chunks of length `n`.

Comment: Oh right, thank you. I just realised though, the list that I am using is a combination of three other lists, I shouldn't have combined these in the first place. If I had three lists of all the same length, how could I achieve the same result as this (pull the first item from the first list and combine it with the first item from the second and third list, and so on)

Comment: `zip(list1, list2, list3)` but you should really ask a different question.

Comment: `zip(l1, l2, l3)` should do the work. If the lists turn out not to be of the same length, the resulting zip will have the length of the shortest list and excess elements in the longer lists will be ignored

Comment: @AChampion I think that question would be immediately deleted as a dupe :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
chunks = [data[x:x+3] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 3)]
```

It will make sublists with 3 items