# How do I split a Very huge string And string without spaces?(python3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.x

Firstly I have this long string

```
s = '1MichaelAngelo'
```

How can I get the output as

```
new_s = '1 Michael Angelo'
```

and as a list

```
new_list = [1,'Michael', 'Angelo']
```

Note: I have like a thousand I parsed from an html.

Secondly, I have this huge string (consists of names and numbers up to 1000]). E.g

```
1\nfirstName\nlastName\n.......999\nfirstName\nlastName
```

where `\n` denotes a newline.

How can I extract data from it to output something like:

```
[1, 'Michael', 'Emily], [2,'Mathew','Jessica'], [3, 'Jacob', 'Ashley ']
```

and so on.

Comment: use split() to convert string to list .But please show your attempt

Comment: Yes I tried to use split() but it just dumped each word into a list which isn't what I want

Comment: It gave me something like [1,'Michael','this','that's,.. ] all in one list

Comment: The first one gave me " 1 M I c h a e l A n g e l o " when I used  .join()

Answer (score 2):

Two questions, two answers. Next time please ask one question at a time.

```
import re
s = '1MichaelAngelo'
[int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+',s)] + re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*',s)
>>> [1, 'Michael', 'Angelo']
```

or, alternatively,

```
import re
s = '1MichaelAngelo'
[int(x) if re.match(r'\d+',x) else x for x in re.findall(r'\d+|[A-Z][^A-Z]*',s)]
```

where `re.findall` splits the longer string on the required boundaries;

and

```
import re
s = '1\nfirstName\nlastName\n999\nfirstName2\nlastName2'
[[int(x) if re.match(r'\d+',x) else x for x in s.split('\n')[i:i+3]] for i in range(0,len(s.split('\n')),3)]
>>> [[1, 'firstName', 'lastName'], [999, 'firstName2', 'lastName2']]
```

where the list comprehension first splits the entire string in threes (using the trick shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15890829/2564301), then scans the newly formed list for integers and convert only these.