# Python how can create a subset from a integer array list based on a range?

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking around a way to get the subset from an integer array based on certain range
For example

```
Input
array1=[3,5,4,12,34,54]

#Now getting subset for every 3 element

Output
subset= [(3,5,4), (12,34,54)]
```

I know it could be simple, but didn't find the right way to get this output

Appreciated for the help

Thanks

Comment: Try writing some code.  Post the code in your question.  Don't worry if it's ugly or not quite correct, just try it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you split a list every x elements and add those x amount of elements to an new list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890743/how-can-you-split-a-list-every-x-elements-and-add-those-x-amount-of-elements-to)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**:

```
>>> array1 = [3, 5, 4, 12, 34, 54]
>>> subset = [tuple(array1[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(array1), 3)]
>>> subset
[(3, 5, 4), (12, 34, 54)]
```

Links to other relevant documentation:

- **[tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuples)**
- **[ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#ranges)**

Answer (score 1):

```py
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
sets = [tuple(arr[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(arr), 3)]
print(sets)
```

We are taking a range of values from the array that we make into a tuple. The range is determined by the for loop which iterates at a step of three so that a tuple only is create after every 3 items.

Answer (score 1):

you can use code:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
input_list = [3,5,4,12,34,54]
iterables = [iter(input_list)] * 3
slices = zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)
output_list =[]
for slice in slices:
    my_list = [slice]
    # print(my_list)
    output_list = output_list + my_list
print(output_list)
```

You could use the zip_longest function from ***itertools***
https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest